# Update field inside the list using MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have multiple MongoDB documents like this:

```
{
    "_id":"abcde",
    "Students":[
        {"Name":"John","IsNew":true},
        {"Name":"Steve","IsNew":true}
    ],
}

{
    "_id":"fghij",
    "Students":[
        {"Name":"Ron","IsNew":true},
        {"Name":"Mike","IsNew":true}
    ],
}
```

How to update the `IsNew` field to false for all students for every document using C# driver?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UpdateMany` method from MongoDB C# driver with the [positional all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator:

```
var filter = Builders<YourModel>.Filter.Exists(x => x.Students);

FieldDefinition<YourModel, bool> field = "Students.$[].IsNew";
var update = Builders<YourModel>.Update.Set(field, false);

Col.UpdateMany(filter, update);
```

EDIT: you can use `.Exists()` as a filter to make sure that `Students` array is present in all the documents that are being updated

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked but students array is not present in all the documents. If students array is not in the document, then compiler throws error: Students must exist in the document.

Comment: @nff modified my answer

Comment: Thanks @mickl .Is there any way we can filter the documents such that it only updates the elements having IsNew flag as `true`?. With the current approach, filter contains all the documents having `Students` list.

Comment: @nff sorry for the delay, please open new question if you still need help since it significantly changes the scope of current question