# Mongodb C# driver update all subarray elements

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to update a document and set a value to an array of subdocument.
Using the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[]) I have to use the `$[]` operator.

Following [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) link it is now possible to do stuff like this :

```
db.coll.update({}, {$set: {“a.$[].b”: 2}})
Input: {a: [{b: 0}, {b: 1}]}
Output: {a: [{b: 2}, {b: 2}]}
```

For example this request will do the job in my case :

```
db.collection.update(
   { "History": { "$elemMatch": { "status": { "$ne": "PROCESSED" } } } }, 
   { "$set": { "History.$[].flag": false } },
   { "multi": true }
)
```

But I do not find the way to do the `$[]` operator in C# with the driver.
And the driver documentation does not contain the information.

Can someone please provide me a C# sample.

Comment: You can take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511704/update-field-inside-the-list-using-mongodb-c-sharp-driver/54520142#54520142

Comment: @mickl indeed I tried but get the `MongoDB.Driver.MongoWriteException : A write operation resulted in an error. cannot use the part (Quotes of Quotes.$[].DraftStatus) to traverse the element` error

Comment: I would verify if the path is correct. You didn't show your real documents here so we don't know if there's `Quotes` in your path. Second hint - please make sure that MongoDB version you're using supports `$[]` operator.

Comment: @mickl yes my bad was using the `UpdateOne` instead of `UpdateMany`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve it like this:

```cs
            collection.UpdateMany(
                x => x.History.Any(h => h.status != "PROCESSED"),
                Builders<YourType>.Update.Set("History.$[].flag", false));
```

here's an alternative strongly-typed solution:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Test : Entity
    {
        public Event[] History { get; set; }
    }

    public class Event
    {
        public bool flag { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            (new[] {
                new Test { History = new[]{
                    new Event { flag = true, status = "PROCESSED" } } },

                new Test { History = new[]{
                    new Event { flag = true, status = "NOT-PROCESSED" },
                    new Event { flag = true, status = "NOT-PROCESSED" }
                }}
            }).Save();

            var field = Prop.PosAll<Test>(t => t.History[0].flag);

            DB.Update<Test>()
              .Match(t => t.History.Any(h => h.status != "PROCESSED"))
              .Modify(b => b.Set(field, false))
              .Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tryed it but got an exception :
`MongoDB.Driver.MongoWriteException : A write operation resulted in an error.
cannot use the part (Quotes of Quotes.$[].DraftStatus) to traverse the element ({Quotes: [ { _id: ObjectId('000000000000000000000000'), DraftNumber: "54321", Identifier: "Identifier", DraftLabel: "DraftLabel", DraftStatus: "s", CreationDate: new Date(1576054651755), PortfolioId: "s" }, { _id: ObjectId('000000000000000000000000'), DraftNumber: "543221", Identifier: "Identifier1", DraftLabel: "s", DraftStatus: "s", CreationDate: new Date(1576054651755), PortfolioId: "s" } ]})`

Comment: I'm facing issues when the array is empty. I opened another post if you dont mind taking a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59376292/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-update-all-subarray-elements-failed-when-array-is-empty

Answer (score -1):

Let's suppose that you have an object called `History`:

```
public class History : MongoDocument
{
   // here you have some other properties, and you have a list of objects
   public Guid Guid { get; private set; }
   public List<SOME_OBJECT> NAME_OF_THE_ARRAY { get; set; }
}
```

And SOME_OBJECT:

```
public class SOME_OBJECT
{
  // here you have other properties
  public bool Flag { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And you want to update all objects into NAME_OF_THE_ARRAY:

```
public async Task<bool> Update_NAME_OF_THE_ARRAY(string id)
{
  var filter = Builders<History>.Filter.Eq("_id", ObjectId.Parse(id));
  var update = Builders<History>.Update.Combine(
    Builders<History>.Update.Set(x => x.NAME_OF_THE_ARRAY[-1].Name, "test")
    Builders<History>.Update.Set(x => x.NAME_OF_THE_ARRAY[-1].Flag, false);
  var result = await _historyCollection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
  return result.ModifiedCount > 0;
}
```

Comment: the `[-1]` translates to a `$` which results in only the first array element getting updated. in order to target all array elements you need `$[]`.