# Mongodb C# driver update all subarray elements failed when array is empty

Tags: c#, mongodb

Linked to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270818/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-update-all-subarray-elements) I tried and was able to update all sub-array elements of a document. To sum up I want to use the [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[]) operator in C#

Here is the update request in my repository :

```
var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
update = update.Set(x => x.LastUpdateDate, date);
update = update.Set(x => x.EndDate, date);
update = update.Set("Quotes.$[].DraftStatus", Constants.ProjectCloseStatus);

var res = _mongoCollection.UpdateMany(filter, update);
```

It is working very well when the "Quotes" array is not empty.
Unfortunately when the array does not exist, I got the following output in the DB :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df73ac41043a04ee0873253"),
    "Quotes" : {
        "$[]" : {
            "DraftStatus" : "CLOSE"
        }
    }
}
```

And the read operation is failed because of the parse.
When I proceed the update I have the following issue :

> A write operation resulted in an error.   The path 'Quotes' must exist
>   in the document in order to apply array updates.

Comment: I've tried your example but I'm getting `The path 'Quotes' must exist in the document in order to apply array updates.'` exception. What MongoDB version are you using ? What exactly is the state of your object before update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like the error message says, you are only allowed to run array update operations on a field that is an array. if the field has a value of `null` or does not exist, the update will also fail.

the simplest solution is to make the field an empty array when saving the documents so that it looks like this in the db:

```java
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5df9af0e22bb051d0c25c936"),
    "Quotes": [ ]
}
```

which can be easily achieved by giving your c# property a default value like so:

```cs
    public Quote[] Quotes { get; set; } = new Quote[0];
```

test program:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Test : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Quote[] Quotes { get; set; } = new Quote[0];
    }

    public class Quote
    {
        public bool flag { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            (new[] {
                new Test { Name = "no quotes"},
                new Test { Quotes = new[]{
                    new Quote { flag = true, status = "PROCESSED" } } },

                new Test { Quotes = new[]{
                    new Quote { flag = true, status = "NOT-PROCESSED" },
                    new Quote { flag = true, status = "NOT-PROCESSED" }
                }}
            }).Save();

            var field = Prop.PosAll<Test>(t => t.Quotes[0].flag);

            DB.Update<Test>()
              .Match(_ => true)
              .Modify(b => b.Set(field, false))
              .Execute();
        }
    }
}
```